# Automatic Migrations Set Connection String in code .NET MVC

Tags: entity-framework, automatic-migration

How to configure Entity Framework to use different connection string when executing migrations and when working with the database.

The reason for that is quite simple, I do not want to have sa login for the website, but I want to be able to execute migrations.

Answer (score 0):

After not finding anything on the web for how to do that, the Object Explorer helped.

The EF Migration `Configuration` class (where `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true` is set)
has also a property named `TargetDatabase`.

This can be set to whatever connection string you want like so:

```
TargetDatabase = new System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbConnectionInfo(
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString,
            ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ProviderName);
```